# cursor: pointer doesn't work on :after element?

Tags: html, css

I'm viewing the below example in Chrome and can't seem to get `cursor: pointer` to work on the `:after` element of `li`. Is there a way to get around this?

http://jsfiddle.net/qKMPQ/2/

Comment: weird.. adding it to the li without the :after pseudo class works.

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug because it works with Firefox.

Comment: Reported as [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240119) in May 2013; no update since Sept 13

Comment: same kind of issue but in IE : [cursor:pointer on pseudo element IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426734/cursorpointer-on-pseudo-element-ie)

Comment: Use css **pointer-events: none;** on the li element, **pointer-events: auto;** on the pseudo-class ::after or ::before.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of setting the `cursor: pointer` on the `:after` element, set it on the entire `li` and it will show up on both.

**Edit:**
For those of you trying to have different cursors on the `li` and its `:after` pseudo-element, you simply need to explicitly define the `cursor` property of the content inside the `li`. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qKMPQ/20/

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
li { cursor: pointer; }
a {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: help;
    display: block; }
li:after {
    content: "";
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block; }
```

Comment: but what if i need different cursors in li and its :after pseudo-element?

Comment: @Wex any idea what to do if I only have text in the `<li>`, but I still need another cursor on my `:after` pseudo-element?

Comment: No worked for me because div yellow don't have action for execute link.

Comment: @AdrianoResende the purpose of the example was to show different cursors on an `:after` element

Comment: Use  css **pointer-events: none;** on the li element, **pointer-events: auto;** on the pseudo-class ::after or ::before.

Comment: @DenisGiffeler has the right answer because it accounts for when the element with `cursor: pointer` consists _only_ of pseudo-elements and __text nodes__