# Cursor change on icon-font characters

Tags: css, cursor

I use entypo icon font for things like open and close buttons on a webpage. Classes like *entypo-desiredcharacter* are assinged to html elements, the icon itself is addes as a pseudo element. On hover, I do not want the cursor to change to the edit-text thing, but just stay the same. I tried

```
[class*="entypo-"], [class*="entypo-"]:before {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It didn't work. What else can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cursor: pointer doesn't work on :after element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296239/cursor-pointer-doesnt-work-on-after-element)

Comment: Nope, I also tried using it on the parent element instead of the pseudo element, didn't work either.

Comment: In that case I suspect there is more to this story, check out http://jsfiddle.net/QLtsX/ where you can see that the cursor changes to a hand on hover of the entire element, including css generated `:before` content.

Answer (score -1):

well cursor: pointer will show a hand.  have you tried cursor:none - also why is it on :before, shouldn't it be on :hover?  Sorry if I misunderstand the question.

Comment: `:before` is valid css, for creating and/or selecting pseudo-elements. Also, why would you want no cursor? Did you mean `cursor: default;`?

Comment: also I know :before is valid, but it looks like he said "on hover" so why would he use :before, it should be :hover right?  Sorry if misunderstanding here.

Comment: Well, the `cursor` property only applies when the mouse cursor is hovering over the element, so `:hover` would be redundant.

Comment: Didn't know that.  I'll change my button classes haha, thanks :)