# cursor:pointer on pseudo element IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element, mouse-cursor

I am implementing a close button on an element containing text with CSS. The close button is generated content from a pseudo element with `content:'X';`. I need the cursor to become a pointer on that "X" so I used :

```
cursor:pointer;
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer (testing on IE11 windows 7).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7ufwyst2/)** *(test in IE)*

I also tried with `cursor:hand;` but it doesn't solve the issue. How can I make the cursor a **pointer while hovering the "X" but not on the text of the div?**

*Relevant code :*

```css
div{
    font-size:2em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div::before{
    content:'X';
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

**--EDIT--**

I am aware that making a child or sibling in the markup and applying `cursor:pointer;` to it will work but I would like to minimize markup and use a pseudo element for the close button as it has no semantic value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really late to the game, but I just now figured out a solution to this problem.

This solution allows a **pointer on the child element**, while **retaining a default cursor on the parent element**.

*(See the accepted answer here for a solution that doesn't include keeping the parent element's cursor default: [cursor: pointer doesn't work on :after element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296239/cursor-pointer-doesnt-work-on-after-element))*

First of all, for this hacky solution, you have to give up the ability to interact with the parent element using the mouse.

Set the parent element to `cursor: pointer`.

Then, setting the parent element to `pointer-events: none` will allow you to "click/hover through" the parent element.

Then, for the pseudo element, just re-enable pointer events with `pointer-events: auto`.

Voila!

```css
div{
    font-size:2em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    
    /* remove ability to interact with parent element */
    pointer-events: none;

    /* apply pointer cursor to parent element */
    cursor:pointer;

    /* make it more obvious which is child and which parent for example*/
    background: darkred;
}
div::before{
    content:'X';

    display:block;
    text-align:right;

    /* restore ability to interact with child element */
    pointer-events: auto;        

    /* make it more obvious which is child and which parent for example*/
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

Comment: Although this diables interaction on the parent it does solve the issue for the pseudo element in IE. Good job

Comment: I had a eureka moment in trying to solve the problem for myself while reading your question, figured I'd share.  I realize it's not perfect, but I'm working on a virus that will delete EVERY COPY OF IE EVER. (kidding...?)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it's not working in pseudo elements in IE, 
What I'm use to do is add `cursor: ponter` to main element.

If you need to add `cursor: pointer` to pseudo element only, than only way is to add child element

like:

```
<div><span></span>some text</div>

div{
   font-size:2em;
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
}
div > span{
   cursor:pointer;
}
div > span::before{
   content:'X';
   display:block;
   text-align:right;
}
```

But than is no point to using pseudo class...

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ufwyst2/17/)

Comment: I was aware of this and this is what I will do if I can't find a solution but I would like to minimize markup and use a pseudo element for that close button

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
        <div id="closebutton">
            X
        </div>
        some text
    </div>
```

**css:**

```
div{
    font-size:2em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div#closebutton{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ufwyst2/21/)

Comment: I was aware that making a child or sibling would work. It is what I will do if I can't find a solution but I would like to minimize markup and use a pseudo element for that close button.

Answer (score -2):

demo

```css
div{
    font-size:2em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
div:after{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    content:'X';
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    some text
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work in IE. Could you consider adding info of why this solution is different than the code in the qusetion considering the `cursor:pointer;` not working in IE?

Answer (score -3):

In order to make IE 7,8,9,10 behave like regular browsers that can deal with pseudo selectors, I always use IE7.js, a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser. It fixes many HTML and CSS issues related to Internet Explorer. An alternative would be modernizr.js which is a good implementation to get pseudo selectors working with IE. I hope, that helps.