# some CSS of a:before in IE9 don't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

```css
a:before {
    content:"Yahoo ";
    cursor: help;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">aaa</a>
```

In IE9, cursor and text-decoration could not work correctly. Why?

Comment: this is probably the same issue as this : [cursor:pointer on pseudo element IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426734/cursorpointer-on-pseudo-element-ie)