# Cannot click on ::after on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML and CSS code, and it works fine on Chrome. However, on Firefox, the behavior is different.

```css
button#groupToggle {
    background: 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
    color: #222;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button#groupToggle::after {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
    color: #f8971d;
    content: '>';
    display: inline-block;
    font: 900 12px/2.1 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1px;
    width: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: ;
}
```

```html
<button id="groupToggle">
  <span>All selected</span>
</button>
```

After the All Selected, there is a button that is created through pseudo CSS (after). It can be clicked when hovering on Chrome but not on Firefox. Any thoughts?

Firefox version: 64.0

Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zymvPj (Please use Firefox to test it).

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426734/cursorpointer-on-pseudo-element-ie

Comment: Thanks @danielarend. I think it's for IE not Firefox.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when I click it? I click it on chrome and nothing happens

Comment: It acts like Firefox does not propagate any events from it. `left: calc(100% - 2em);` on the :after element will push it over top of the 'hit area' of the button. Not a solution, but a workaround in this case.

Comment: If you don't want user to click on the All select text, then don't make it a button instead of making it a button and then disabling pointer events. it's counter intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is no way to make it behave the same way as it does in Chrome. `:after` and `:before` are not treated as DOM elements by Firefox. You can however, cheat it a little bit. Changing behave for all browsers. That is my proposition of solution to look the same and behave as you would like it to do.

```css
button#groupToggle {
    background: 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
    color: #222;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    min-width: 224px;
  /* increased by 24px (after width) */
    padding: 8px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 0;
}

button#groupToggle::after {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
    color: #f8971d;
    content: '>';
    display: inline-block;
    font: 900 12px/2.1 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1px;
    width: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: ;
    right: -1px; 
    /* -1px to neutralize border */
}

/* ONLY TO SHOW IT WORKING */
button#groupToggle:focus {
   outline: red solid 10px;
   -moz-outline: red solid 10px
}
```

```html
<button id="groupToggle">
  <span>All selected</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Font-Awesome 5 - Pseudo-elements

### Requirements for Free Solid Version

1. Have this in the `<head>` tag:

> [`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">`](https://fontawesome.com/start#cdn)

2. [In your stylesheet](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#how-they-work):

> ```
> .icon::after {
>   display: inline-block;
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-variant: normal;
>   text-rendering: auto;
>   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
> }
>
> .arrow::after {
>   content: '\f105';
>   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
>   font-weight: 900;
> }
> ```
>
> The `content` property needs [Unicode](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) not `>`

3. Those two classes names are arbitrary but be sure that they are on the same tag:

> ```
> <button class='icon arrow'></button>
> ```

---

#### Absolute Positioning

Font-Awesome (or lack thereof) wasn't the problem, but I had to address the elephant in the room. Anyhow, `left:100%` pushed the part out of the button's border and looks as if Firefox treats the pseudo-element like it doesn't belong to the button, while apparently Chrome remembers. The solution is simply: remove `left:100%` and add `right:0`

---

### Demo

```css
button#groupToggle {
  background: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
  color: #222;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 6px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon::after {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6ed;
  color: #f8971d;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.7;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -1px;
  width: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#groupToggle::after {
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

<button id="groupToggle" class='icon'>
  <span>All selected</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne. Your solution also works on Firefox.

Comment: No problem, @DaleNguyen Happy coding.