# CSS - Pointer on element, but default cursor (arrow) on :after?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with `cursor: pointer;`, and would like for its `:after` pseudo-element to have `cursor: default;` (the normal mouse arrow).

```css
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two:after {
  content: "\2027";
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: aqua;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

But no matter what I set `cursor` to in the `:after` pseudo-element, it always displays `pointer`.

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L5pyr342/)** is a Fiddle of the issue

None of the SO posts that I can find provide a solution to the issue.

**Edit #1**

Based on comment, this might be a Safari-only issue. Tested in Chrome, and all is well.

Comment: Displays default cursor for me

Comment: @John I just tested in Chrome and it worked. Seems to be a Safari issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cursor: pointer doesn't work on :after element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296239/cursor-pointer-doesnt-work-on-after-element)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a know issue in Safari, others having this problem too.

What you can do is, put the content of your "two" class in another html tag and apply the style on those. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/cornelraiu/L5pyr342/1/:

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <span class="pointer">
            Text
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: red;
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.two:after {
    content: "\2027";
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: aqua;
    color: #000;
}
```

I know this is a "hack" but it works on all browsers.

EDIT: There seems to be an answer to the same issue here but on an old version of Chrome and still present on the newer versions of Safari: [cursor: pointer doesn't work on :after element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296239/cursor-pointer-doesnt-work-on-after-element) resolved in the same way I have it :)